# Cannot connect rabbitmq pod from another pod k8s

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I'm current trying deploy an application to connect the rabbitmq.

The application and rabbitmq are on different pod on the same cluster node.

And I can not connect to rabbitMQ via servicename or cluster IP.

Do you have any idea about this problem?

The exeception on app

```
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

Here is rabbitmq_deployment.yaml

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: rabbitmq
   namespace: test
 spec:
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       run: rabbitmq
   replicas: 1
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         run: rabbitmq
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: rabbitmq
         image: rabbitmq_delay_v3.7
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
 ---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: rabbitmq-svc
   namespace: test
   labels:
     run: rabbitmq
 spec:
   type: NodePort
   ports:
   - name: rabbit-web
     protocol: TCP
     port: 15672
     targetPort: 15672
     nodePort: 30000
   - name: rabbit-svc
     protocol: TCP
     port: 5672
     targetPort: 5672
   selector:
     run: rabbitmq
```

Here is app_deployment.yaml

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: app_test
      namespace: test
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          run: app_test
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            run: app_test
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: app1
            image: my_app_image
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            env:
              - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
                value: "Staging"
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: app-test-svc
      namespace: test
      labels:
        run: app-test
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - name: app_test_port
        protocol: TCP
        port: 80
        targetPort: 80
        nodePort: 30203
      selector:
        run: app_test
```

And here is config to connect rabbitmq on app

```
"QueueConfig": {
        "HostName": "rabbitmq-svc",
        "UserName": "guest",
        "Pwd": "guest",
        "VirtualHost": "/",
        "Port": 5672,
}
```

Here is output of `kubectl -n test describe avc rabbitmq-svc`

```
  Name:                     rabbitmq-svc
  Namespace:                test
  Labels:                   run=rabbitmq
  Annotations:              Selector:  run=rabbitmq
  Type:                     NodePort
  IP:                       10.103.189.233
  Port:                     rabbit-web  15672/TCP
  TargetPort:               15672/TCP
  NodePort:                 rabbit-web  30000/TCP
  Endpoints:                10.244.1.174:15672
  Port:                     rabbit-svc  5672/TCP
  TargetPort:               5672/TCP
  NodePort:                 rabbit-svc  31425/TCP
  Endpoints:                10.244.1.174:5672
  Session Affinity:         None
  External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
  Events:                   <none>
```

Here is output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-j8494              1/1     Running   1          7d9h
coredns-66bff467f8-jtn5w              1/1     Running   1          7d9h
etcd-master-node                      1/1     Running   1          7d9h
kube-apiserver-master-node            1/1     Running   1          7d9h
kube-controller-manager-master-node   1/1     Running   1          7d9h
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-8gd7b           1/1     Running   1          7d9h
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xj2hw           1/1     Running   1          7d8h
kube-proxy-62wsz                      1/1     Running   1          7d9h
kube-proxy-77g2d                      1/1     Running   0          7d8h
kube-scheduler-master-node            1/1     Running   1          7d9h
```

Comment: Add output of `kubectl describe svc rabbitmq-svc -n test`

Comment: Can you try using `10.244.1.174` ? Also you have any network policy?

Comment: I tried it but cannot. The same exception. I don't think I have any network policy. Can you show me how to check that?

Comment: Are you able to login to rabbitmq management console using that credential? To check network policy use below command `kubectl get netpol -n test`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu that credential is a default of rabbitmq. And I can connect to management site from outsite via nodeport. I checked and I don't have any network policy

Comment: and when I run `kubectl -n test exec -it [podname] -- sh`,  I cannot execute `nslookup` command.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu: I tried and only access via clusterIP of worker machine and NodePort. My worker machine IP is 192.168.1.118:31425. Where am i wrong? It's rather weird if I connect by ip address.

Comment: Are you able to connect to it from outside using the same `QueueConfig`? It seems not a connectivity issue from kubernetes side. I think the `QueueConfig` has some issue

Comment: I don't think so, I just change hostname to Node IP with NodePort. It can be access, but I don't know why it cannot access with service name inside. In bash of Pod, I can't ping or nslookup any service name.

Comment: Okay then maybe DNS within cluster is broken.Edit the question to add output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`. If the coredns pod is not running check logs and add in the question

Comment: Thanks @ArghyaSadhu. I also think about DNS's problem. But I don't know how to investigate it. I added output as your suggest on this post. Please check it out.

Comment: Create a service for the application pod try to connect to it from another test pod. If DNS is broken no service should work..not just rabbitmq

Comment: I installed dashboard k8s, so I see it use service, and I think may be it work.

Comment: Can you connect to rabbitmq from cluster but outside the application pod?

Comment: @KFC_: yes, I can connect rabbitmq from outsite. And now my app only connect to rabbitmq via NodePort of rabbitmq. But I think it doesn't make scene.

Comment: So it works using `31425` but not `5672`?